# string representing date and transform it

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring

To format a string representing date received from other part some transform is required:

```
source:
    std::string s = "20190510";
target:
    std::string t = "05/10/2019";
```

One way is to copy char by char, is there an elegant way to do it beautiful and fast?

UPDATE: Sorry the transform should be from "yyyymmdd" to "mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: How about using `boost::format`?

Comment: sorry cannot use boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the string or copy it, then you are left with the option of *formatting it* only when needed. This can be accomplished with a small utility:

```
struct date_format {
    std::string const& str;
    date_format(std::string const& str) : str(str) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, date_format const& df) {
        return os.write(&df.str[4], 2)
                 .put('/')
                 .write(&df.str[6], 2)
                 .put('/')
                 .write(&df.str[0], 4);
    }
};
```

To be used like this for instance `std::cout << date_format(source);`, [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20789d7083f718f5).

Otherwise it's definitely going to entail copying or moving characters about.

Comment: this can also work on string stream, right? if i want to hold the result instead of print it, just to confirm.

Comment: @fluter - Yes. The general `ostream` parameter makes it possible. You can use this utility to obtain formatted copies too.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/):

```
int main() {
    std::string s = "20190510";
    s.insert(4, "/");
    s.insert(7, "/");
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: insert involves moving of whole block of memory, right? is there any better way?

Comment: Any operation that adds characters to a string might make it move the memory if it doesn't fit anymore. At least the characters after the insert position will have to be moved anyway. I don't think the standard mandates how `insert` has to be implemented, but I guess it should be fairly efficient and avoid obvious performance pitfalls.

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong example, updated my post, this is my bad